# Have ActionLink in Create page return to Parent Details

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I get ActionLink on view to return to details of parent class from create page?

I have an action that works fine on the "edit" view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Client Details", "ClientDetails"
, new { clientId = Model.ClientId })
```

but it fails on the Create page because the model is incomplete or non-existant.
I've tried getting this value from the viewbag, the viewdata but none of them return the values.  keeps coming back as null

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do ,,, but the correct way to redirect to a details view after the creation is thorough the create action method where the user input is posted to ,,,

The example below shows a create action method where a question is created and then the user is redirect to the questions page immediately using the question id that is returned from the service:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Create(QuestionEditorViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

            // Create the question.
            int questionId = _questionAndAnswerService.CreateQuestion(
            model.QuestionSubject,
            model.QuestionBody,
            SessionWrapper.CurrentStudent.StudentId, 
            SessionWrapper.CurrentStudent.DisplayName);

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = questionId});
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: great, but what if the user discards the new item and just wants to return to the details.
the redirecttoaction requires an id and that value doesn't exist until the model is returned